# histogram and KernelDensity in log scale

Tags: python, scikit-learn, histogram, kernel-density

In `plt.hist` I can define logarithmic bins which show up as linearly spaced in log scale (see image). 
Is there a way to do the same with the `bandwidth` of `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity`?
Choosing a single number for `bandwidth` in `KernelDensity`, and plotting in logscale as below, gives non-equally spaced kernel densities.

[image: hist and KernelDensity in log scale]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity


def kernel_density_histo(sig, band=.1):
    X = np.linspace(np.min(sig)*0.9, np.max(sig)*1.1, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
    kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=band).fit(sig[:, np.newaxis])
    dens = np.exp(kde.score_samples(X))
    plt.figure('kernel_density_histo', clear=True)
    plt.semilogx(X,dens, label='kernel')


sig = np.random.lognormal(size=100)
kernel_density_histo(sig)
plt.hist(sig, bins=np.logspace(np.log(np.min(sig)), np.log(np.max(sig)), 30), density=True, rwidth=0.8, label='hist')                                                   
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```